# How can i access btinami kafka from outside?

Tags: apache-kafka, bitnami

I deployed kafka in k8s using this https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/deploy-scalable-kafka-zookeeper-cluster-kubernetes/

how can I access kafka from outside ( preferably NodePort ) without reinstalling with the necessary parameters (required for logstash)?

Comment: if you dont want to reinstall, just edit the service and expose it as Nodeport. update yaml of helm chart next time so it wont get updated back to original

Comment: I tried to change service (Kafka service)  type to node port. After that request to service trough nodeip:port returns just : empty reply. I also tried to use helm update with set of parameters which i found in (https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/infrastructure/kafka/administration/external-access/. So it didn’t work too.